# Set flatpickr datetime on last enabled day does not work

Tags: flatpickr

I have flatpickr date picker on my webpages. Users can select date and time from range from minDate to maxDate. On create form component I also want to set last value, which user select - selectedDate.

**If the *selectedDate* is from last day, flatpicker ignores it.**

My code:

```js
const options: Partial<BaseOptions> = {
    minDate: minDate, // "2020-12-05 00:00"
    maxDate: maxDate, // "2020-12-24 23:59"
    dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i',
    defaultDate: selectedDate, // "2020-12-24 17:00"
    enableTime: true,
};

const picker = <flatpickr.Instance> flatpickr(inputElement, options);
picker.setDate(selectedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging I found a problem. Flatpicker **sets internal maxDate to last midnight** 2020-12-24 23:59 => 2020-12-24 00:00 and inside `setDate()` ignores the selectedDate 2020-12-24 17:00, which is not between minDate maxDate.

I fix that by adding this line of code just before `picker.setDate(selectedDate);`

```js
// ... init the picker ...
picker.set('maxDate', maxDate);
// ... setDate() ...
```

This sets internal maxDate to desired datetime and make your selectedDate work well.